# what to use ? web service VS stored procedure

Tags: spring, web-services, stored-procedures, plsql

I am working on a project and have to choose either i want to invoke directly a web service to get the data i want, or get through a stored procedure and take the 2 methods I need and use them!

I don't know which way to choose, and why?

Any suggestions?
thx

Comment: It's difficult to give any advice since you did not provide any background. Maybe this will be helpful https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/158565, usually I avoid stored procedures for the same reasons that are listed in the link I provided.

Comment: Okey I'll check it now, thank you so much